# Asking for input in an event handler

Tags: dynamic

Why won't

```
EventHandler["text", {"MouseClicked" :> (output = Input[];)}]
```

work?

When I click "text" the kernel hangs.

Comment: can you expand a little more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: The real application would be something like, clicking in a graphics object, and saving the coordinates and a label that I input using Input[]...

Comment: Is that code what you've been using? It contains an error: `"MouseClicked" > action` should be `"MouseClicked" -> action`.

Comment: I use "MouseClicked" :> action, I corrected the error

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Let me remind you three things we 
usually do here: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering 
questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 
3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), 
because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users 
sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves 
your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are facing an issue similar to [**described here**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0mrh4y-6sf9if) . The problem is `Button` has option `Method -> "Queued"` and `EventHandler` does not have anything similar. Here is a way around it:

```
DynamicModule[{output = "click to change"}, Button[Dynamic[output], 
  output = InputString["Enter new text", "click to change"], 
  Method -> "Queued", Appearance -> "Frameless"]]
```

[image]

If you just must use `EventHandler`, then `CreateDialog` is a work around:

```
output = "click to change";
EventHandler[ Dynamic[output], {"MouseClicked" :> 
   CreateDialog[{TextCell["Enter new text"], 
     InputField[Dynamic[output], String], 
     DefaultButton[DialogReturn[output]]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I thought scheduled tasks could help here, but they have the same problem. Might be because scheduled tasks don't need a frontend and Input probably runs in the frontend?